# behavior while loop in c programming

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, post-increment, postfix-operator

output in this case is 1

```
int main() {
    int i = 500;
    while( (i++) != 0 );
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return;
}
```

output in this case is 0

```
int main() {
    int i = 500;
    while( (i=i+1) != 0 );

    printf("%d\n", i);
    return;
}
```

I'm Not sure why  get this different output in every case I mean why 1 in first case and 0 at second case

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: OT: you should indent your code properly on order to make it readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the both programs have undefined behavior. Instead of declaring the variable i as having the signed integer type `int` you should declare it as having the unsigned integer type `unsigned int` to make the programs correct.

This while loop

```
while( (i++) != 0 );
```

stops its iterations when the expression `i++` is equal to `0`. So when the variable `i` is equal to `0` the loop stops. But due to the postfix increment operator its value is incremented and becomes equal to `1`.

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.
> As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
> is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it).

This while loop

```
while( (i=i+1) != 0 );
```

also stops its iterations when `i` is equal to `0` after the assignment `i = i + 1`.